# Rotated text issue in print preview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, rotation

I have an application with the Jquery Rotate plugin to rotate the div contents.

Its rotating contents fine in document.ready() function.

```
    <script src="App_Themes/jquery.rotate-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.rotation').jqrotate(-90);
          $('.id-card.invert').jqrotate(-180);


      });
   </script>
```

and the result is:

[image]

But while taking print preview, the rotated content shown as normal content.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you need to use @media print .....

Answer (score 0):

Use the media query to detect the media and use your code there:

```
if (window.matchMedia("print").matches) {
    //use your code here
}
```

Comment: I am taking the print preview by right clicking the web page